# xolo q1011 can't root

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, sync

I have a xolo q1011. I tried to root but none of the methods vroot,towelroot,pieroot,sideload,cwm worked.  Is there any other way to root my phone so that I can install cm ROMs. Its in version 4.4.2 it have the Google sync problem as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it. The 1.7.8 version of Vroot can root my phone

Answer (score 0):

Kingoroot.

http://www.kingoapp.com

I hope it will work for you

Comment: tried Kingoroot,SmartRoot, and few other similiar softwares no hope. Is there anyway I can manually do it?